# Cannot Run Postgres (psql) locally

Tags: macos, postgresql, psql

Whenever I try to run `psql` locally i.e. `$ psql -d template1 -U postgres` I receive `-bash: psql: command not found`

I've installed the Postgres Mac app, but when I click open psql I get...

```
Last login: Tue Jan  6 16:30:17 on ttys001
admins-MacBook-Air:~ surajkapoor$ /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/psql ; exit;
psql: FATAL:  database "surajkapoor" does not exist
logout

[Process completed]
```

This doesn't make sense to me. I assumed installing the mac app install postgres locally.

Comment: Why do you specify the needed parameters when using `psql` but not when using the full path to the tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the directory where the psql file is to the PATH variable of the mac which would be

```
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/
```

Opening psql without parameters will attempt to connect to a database with the name of the current user, if you don't want to add the directory to the PATH variable you can just put the whole address on the console and it should work

```
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/psql -d template1 -U postgres
```